# Prove that $ \frac{a^2}{a+b}+ \frac{b^2}{b+c} \geq \frac{3a+2b-c}{4} $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

> Prove that:
>   $$ \frac{a^2}{a+b} + \frac{b^2}{b+c} \geq \frac{3a+2b-c}{4} : (a, b, c)\in \mathbb{R}^+$$

This is just one of these questions where you just have no idea how to start. First impressions, I don't see how any known inequality can be used, and I also don't want to go just make everything as a sum then solve it.

I always was bad at inequalities and I don't know why. I did the other exercise just fine, but inequalities are hard for me. This is from a high-school olympiad.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
\frac{a^2}{a+b} + \frac{b^2}{b+c} &\geqslant \frac{3a + 2b - c}{4}\\
\iff \frac{a^2}{a+b} - a + \frac{b^2}{b+c} - b &\geqslant - \frac{a + 2b + c}{4}\\
\iff -\frac{ab}{a+b} - \frac{bc}{b+c} &\geqslant - \frac{a+b}{4} - \frac{b+c}{4}\\
\iff \frac{(a+b)^2 - 4ab}{4(a+b)} + \frac{(b+c)^2 - 4bc}{4(b+c)} &\geqslant 0.
\end{align}$$

Since all numbers are positive, the denominators are positive, and $(x+y)^2 - 4xy = (x-y)^2 \geqslant 0$.